# vaadin widgetset do not work. bug in maven plugin vaadin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, widget, vaadin

I've create a vaadin application with maven using the following comand:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin
> -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.7.12-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=myapplication -Dversion=0.1 -Dpackaging=war

It has created a right project; Now I'm going to create a custom widget, follow the instruction on
https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/gwt/gwt-eclipse

The wizard new-->other--> Vaadin 8 widget creates the necessary file:

[image]

But when I try to compile I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project myapplication: Compilation failure:
> Compilation failure:  [ERROR]
> /C:/Users/fmi/eclipse-workspace/myapplication/src/main/java/com/example/client/mycomponent/MyComponentWidget.java:[3,37]
> package com.google.gwt.user.client.ui does not exist [ERROR]
> /C:/Users/fmi/eclipse-workspace/myapplication/src/main/java/com/example/client/mycomponent/MyComponentWidget.java:[6,40]
> cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class Label

I know that may be I have to add dependency in the pom, but I'm asking why the wizard has this bug?
Note in the picture I see Vaadin 8 widget, while the project has been created with archetype 7.7

Is a bug in the wizard or a mistake by me?
thanks

Comment: You seem to be adding a Vaadin 8 widget to a Vaadin 7 project. Not likely to mix well.

Comment: Tip: Unless you have a very specific need for Vaadin 7 or 8, I suggest using 14 for any long-term deployments or the latest (now 22) for learning and experimenting. The versions 7, 8, and 14/22 are three very different generations of Vaadin technology.

Comment: Fix your imports first: 
> package com.google.gwt.user.client.ui does not exist [ERROR]
> cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class Label

Comment: @Basil Bourque: yes Vaadin 7 project and Vaadin 8 widget, there is no way I know to have Vaadin 7 on the plugin; And I have to work with Vaadin 7 unfortunately;

Comment: @Eisenknurr well it is a wizard why I have to include manualy them in the pom? Obviously I can do that But is that the way to do?

Comment: Besides even if I use Vaadin 8 project and Vaadin 8 widgets the issue still remain;

Comment: Your `MyComponentWidget.java` does not compile. That error holds no other information. So fix that and see what happens. IIRC widget files didn't change between v7 and v8. For what it's worth you shouldn't be doing v7 Vaadin anyways, unless you need support for IE11 or so. Have a look at a working v7 project's widgetset file like https://github.com/TatuLund/grid-scroll-extension/blob/vaadin7/GridScrollExtension-addon/src/main/resources/org/vaadin/extension/gridscroll/WidgetSet.gwt.xml

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved adding:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is necessary to compile widgets; It is still unclear why in the documentation has not reported.

Comment: There's a Client-Side Development section in the Vaadin 7 docs, the required dependencies are listed in https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/clientside/clientside-installing